# How to cat file with limit of printed characters from each line?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I would like to cat file, but with limit to max length to each line. For example I a have file with 10 lines each have 10000 characters and I would like to print first 100 characters from each line. Is something like that possible with cat or some alternative? thx.

Comment: Could you give more details on the reasons for this? Actually, doing a cat in a window showing just 100 char per line would do the joy. But I doubt this is what you want.

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen Terminals will wrap lines rather than truncating them, so more than the first 100 characters from each line of the file would still be printed.

Comment: Depending on your ultimate goal, wouldn't it be better for you to simply use a text viewer that chops long lines, such as `less -S` (or type `-S` runtime) or `mcview` and press `F2`, or something similar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the `cut` tool you can limit the output to 100. Since you only interested in the `characters` hence the columns they occupy this should do that nicely:

```
cut -c-100 file
```

In case you wish to remove the spaces in there this would help:

```
sed 's/ //g' file | cut -c-100
```

See: `man cut`

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ print substr( $0, 0, 100 ) }' file
```

Getting rid of spaces again if required:

```
awk '{ gsub (" ", "", $0); print substr( $0, 0, 100 ) }' file
```

**AWK**:

`gsub (" ", "", $0)`: find `" "`(spaces) and replace with `""` globally in target string `$0`.

`substr( $0, 0, 100 )`: it returns 100 number of chars from string $0, starting at position 0.

Answer (score 2):

#### Shell

`bash` and `ksh` way to achieve this would be:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ];do printf "%s\n" "${line:0:100}"; done < input.txt
```

Here we take advantage of parameter expansion in form `${parameter:start:offset}`  to print from starting point till offset. Should be noted that this [isn't specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) and doesn't work in `dash` ( the default `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu).

#### Perl

```
perl -ne 'printf "%s\n",substr($_,0,100)' input.txt
```

This takes advantage of built-in [substr](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) function.

#### Python

`python` is Python 2.7 on Ubuntu:

```
python -c 'import sys; print "\n".join(map(lambda x: x[:100],sys.stdin.readlines()))' < input.txt
```

For python3, enclose arguments to `print` with braces:

```
python3 -c 'import sys; print("\n".join(map(lambda x: x[:100],sys.stdin.readlines())))' < input.txt
```

This takes advantage of shell's redirection for file's contents into python's `stdin` stream, then reads all lines into list from the `stdin`,. The `map()` function allows us to process that list via `lambda x: x[:100]`, obtaining a new list, where each item is a slice of each corresponding line, 100 characters long.  `"\n".join()` lets us combine the list of strings into one again with newline as separator.

Comment: +1 Great programming examples Serge. I think the `bash` example can be copy and pasted as an easy to comprehend one-liner in the terminal.